# We were all wounded at "Waunde:d" Knee

Tags: differences

We've all heard the song. I'm just wondering whether it's wounded or "waunde:d" knee. Is there a river in the vicinity of "Wounded Knee" that is twisted or turned (waunde:d) or is the site named after the battle where everyone was wounded?

Comment: I haven't found an origin for the name Wounded Knee (George R Stewart doesn't mention it in _Names on the Land_, but I have always supposed that it was a translation of a native name. Certainly it cannot be anything to do with 'wound', the past of 'wind'.

Comment: I've no idea what song you're talking about.

Comment: You might get a better response at [history.se]

Answer (score 5):

*Wounded* would necessarily be pronounced /ˈwundɪd/ as in *festering wound*.  *Wounded* as in *twisted* isn't a word - *wound* (/waʊnd/) is the correct form.  *Wind* (/waɪnd/) is the present tense form and *wound* is the past tense form.

Comment: Allready found it: the kind of river I am referring to would be called a "winding river". This being the case it should be "Winding Knee". Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @BurtNettle You can accept the answer (if it was helpful) by clicking the check mark under the up/down buttons next to the answer.